# LimeSurvey deletes cookies after close browser

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies, survey, limesurvey

Looking for assistance with LimeSurvey.
Need to fix if possible how to save customer session with cookies and don't delete them when customer close a browser with survey.
We are using survey to login with Token. When customer answer questions and don't finish it, like in a middle of survey he close his browser, and reopen it again in a new browser he needs to login again with Token and start with a new survey.

But is there any chance to save data in user browser? Because the same token are using a lot of people from one company, so different people who uses same token would see already answered questions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting for that called Token Persistence.
https://manual.limesurvey.org/Participant_settings#Enable_token-based_response_persistence

You can set it from the survey settings.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But is there any chance to save data in user browser? Because the same token are using a lot of people from one company, so different people who uses same token would see already answered questions. Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to share token but save the temp responses on the browser and not in the backend?

Comment: Same token will be used by group of people, who login from same IP address but different pc’s. So some how need to save answers on their pc’s browsers if any idea?

Comment: How many questions are we talking about? You could create a plugin to save responses temporarily. That's the objective right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Questions depends from survey, but it's like from 5-10 questions. Temporary save responses, but any advice how to relate them with user browser or any other minds?

Comment: If you save responses temporarily using cookies, they will be related to the browser.